# How to setup gulp-typescript for Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp, ecmascript-6, angular

currently I'm using `tsc` compiler with watch flag from prompt. It works well, load all definition files and compile correctly each angular2 file. However is very uncomfortable to use through the shell window.

My goal is to create a gulp task that can translate any typescript file according to angular2 definitions. I've involved `gulp-typescript`, seems easy to use, so this is the code:

```
var tsProject = $.typescript.createProject(paths.src + '/tsconfig.json');
gulp.task('typescript', function() {
  gulp
    .src([
      paths.src + '/*.ts'
    ])
    .pipe($.typescript(tsProject)).js
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.tmp));
});
```

And this is the folder structure:

```
...
src/
---- app/
-------- ts/
------------ *.ts
---- typings/
-------- angular2/
------------ angular2.d.ts
------------ http.d.ts
-------- es6-promise/
------------ ...
-------- rx/
------------ ...
-------- tsd.d.ts
---- *.ts
---- tsconfig.json
gulpfile.js
...
```

The tsconfig file has no `files` list, so the compiler should check any ts file inside `src` (at any level).

When the task is invoked i receive this errors:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2'.
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/http'.
```

How can I tell to typescript compiler which `d.ts` files to use?

Comment: have you declared amd-references in your files like this
``/// <amd-dependency path="typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />``?

Comment: See this project, it may be useful : [ng2-play.ts](https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/ng2-play.ts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is looks like you have not declared `amd-reference` in your files yet.

Try to declare in files where you import your modules something like that:

```
/// <amd-dependency path="./src/typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />
/// <amd-dependency path="./src/typings/angular2/http.d.ts" />

import angular2 = require("angular2");
import http = require("http")
```

`/// <amd-dependency` tells compiler that special modules exists in system and give possibility to compile without errors

Comment: Thank you! very easy, when I started the project I used these references lines, but `tsc` works also without, so I removed them. Now I can say welcome again!

Comment: I`m glad to help you!:) Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to add definitions to gulp.src. Something like this:

```
var tsProject = $.typescript.createProject(paths.src + '/tsconfig.json');
gulp.task('typescript', function() {
  gulp
    .src([
      paths.src + '/app/**/*.ts',
      paths.src + '/typings/**/*.d.ts'
    ])
    .pipe($.typescript(tsProject)).js
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.tmp));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This also had me cursing and swearing for a while. Make sure you have this in the compilerOptions node of your tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
  }
}
```